# Много поврежденных файлов Windows. Очень

Tags: windows, драйвер

В общем. Начну с небольшого вступления. В начале осени все работало прекрасно. После что то произошло с ноутбуком Acer, видимо под влиянием Китайских сетей. (Я в Китае на данное время) Что я сделал, я так и не понял. Но первое отображение проблемы нашел в играх любого типа, а именно полное и беспрерывное торможение\лаги. Не важно, насколько она старая, и настройки графики тоже не влияют. Дальше, я обнаружил что один из видеодрайверов не работает ([image: Тут соответственно сама ошибка]
Путем долгих обходов всех сайтов поддержки, ничего не помогло, ни дополнительные утилиты, ни сама поддержка, сказали, переустанавливайте Винду. Я пытался, я боролся, но ничего не помогло, ладно. Спустя месяц я решил вернуть все к заводским настройкам, но не тут то было. При обновлении системы выходит еще одна ошибка, утверждающая, что что-то где-то повреждено. Видимо, есть нецельные файлы, подумал я. и  сделал sfc /scannow. (Так проще)
Дальше вышло вот это : "

Программа защиты ресурсов Windows обнаружила поврежденные файлы, но не
может восстановить некоторые из них.
Подробные сведения см. в файле CBS.Log, который находится по следующему пути:
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Например, C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Подробные сведения
включены в файл журнала, предоставляемый флагом /OFFLOGFILE.
"
Хорошо, зашел в логи, соответственно ничего не понял.

CSI    00004eb7 Error: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory \??\C:\WINDOWS\Inf.NET CLR Networking 4.0.0.0\0000 in component NETFX4CLIENTCoreComp, version 10.0.15680.229, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2019-04-27 19:48:26, Info                  CSI    00004eb8 Error: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory \??\C:\WINDOWS\Inf.NET CLR Networking in component NETFX4CLIENTCoreComp, version 10.0.15680.229, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2019-04-27 19:48:26, Info                  CSI    00004eb9 Error: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory \??\C:\WINDOWS\Inf.NET CLR Networking\0000 in component NETFX4CLIENTCoreComp, version 10.0.15680.229, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2019-04-27 19:48:26, Info                  CSI    00004eba Error: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory \??\C:\WINDOWS\Inf.NET CLR Data in component NETFX4CLIENTCoreComp, version 10.0.15680.229, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

2019-04-27 19:48:26, Info                  CSI    00004ebb Error: Overlap: Duplicate ownership for directory \??\C:\WINDOWS\Inf.NET CLR Data\0000 in component NETFX4CLIENTCoreComp, version 10.0.15680.229, arch Host= amd64 Guest= x86, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}

Было много ошибок такого типа, а потом он просто

2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20190330180030.cab to WER report.
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20190330171138.cab to WER report.
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CBS    Added C:\WINDOWS\Logs\CBS\CbsPersist_20190330100402.cab to WER report.
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CBS    Could not get active session for current session file logging [HRESULT = 0x80004003 - E_POINTER]
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to add pending.xml.bad to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CBS    Not able to add SCM.EVM to Windows Error Report. [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CSI    0000547f [SR] Committing transaction
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CSI    00005480 Creating NT transaction (seq 1)
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CSI    00005481 Created NT transaction (seq 1) result 0x00000000, handle @0xc40
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CSI    00005482@2019/4/27:16:49:00.781 Beginning NT transaction commit...
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CSI    00005483@2019/4/27:16:49:00.781 CSI perf trace:
CSIPERF:TXCOMMIT;82
2019-04-27 19:49:00, Info                  CSI    00005484 [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
2019-04-27 19:51:02, Info                  CBS

*Trusted Installer is shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP
2019-04-27 19:51:02, Info                  CBS    TiWorker signaled for shutdown, going to exit.*

Такой вот я чайник, что не знаю как, о угробил свой ноутбук... Прощу помочь вас мне что-то сделать, но только не восстановление через образ с USB или возвращение на 7 -_-. (Я мог скинуть что то не, так как не сильно шарю, но надеюсь, что моя проблема понятно. Если еще что то нужно в виде логов, я буду тут.

---

Проблема не в диске, вы понимаете? Этому ноутбуку не больше полугода. Проблема в том, что даже после переустановки видеоадаптер не хочет работать (Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620.) При попытке установить у меня пишет что Не удалось установить: ‎30.‎04.‎2019 – 0x8024ce2b
Моя проблема заключается в этом.

Comment: Прошу забить на грамматические ошибки, поторопился :d

Comment: Чё `S.M.A.R.T.` говорит?

Comment: Прогу для просмотра еще  не устанавливал,он может дать полезную информацию? В этой области я уже не спец

Comment: Хорошую инфу может дать сканирование через `MHDD`, но smart для начала тоже сойдёт.

Comment: Там все в порядке, все зеленые

Comment: Ты про смарт или про рисунок mhdd?

Comment: Точные значения S.M.A.R.T. в студию, зелёные кузнечики на лужайке нам ни о чём не говорят

Answer (score 1):

В удачном для вас, но маловероятном варианте достаточно переустановить Windows (или восстановить из образа).

Неудачный, но более вероятный вариант - замена жесткого диска и пункт 1.

Ситуация выглядит очень похоже на умирание диска. Простые решения вроде починки файловой системы не помогут, но можете на всякий случай попробовать.

Comment: Вот, я попытался скачать образ, скачал, но он не хочет устанавливаться. "По неизвестной причине запуск этого средства на вашем компьютере не удался. Если проблемы не исчезнут .. ля ля ля... Код ошибки: 0х80070002 - 0хА001А". В этом вся проблема, что переустановить я не могу

Comment: Что некий скачанный образ не устанавливается, это еще ни о чем не говорит. Другой образ может и установиться. Лучше всего, оригинальную систему как-то восстановить. А первым делом SMART смотрите, если диск помер, то все эти упражнения напрасная потеря времени.

Comment: Все зеленые, все в порядке

Comment: @Loyale, кто зеленый - кузнечики на лужайке? SMART это цифры. Если вы сами не можете интерпретировать, сделайте новый вопрос с ними.